# Solving a transcendental equation for a result that can be plotted

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to solve the following transcendental equation for `p` as function of `b`.

```
(a*b/c)*Sqrt[m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2] - 
  2 ArcTan[Sqrt[((p*c/b)^2 - m2^2)/(m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2)]] == 0
```

where `p` must to satisfy

```
m2*b < p < m1*b
```

and

```
a = 2; c = 3; m1 = 1.5; m2 = 1.49;
```

I want to plot `p` *vs* `b` where `b` runs from $0$ to $2$.

I already tried all day, but I cannot find a solution. I tried with [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) without success. Can you me give a suggestion for dealing with this problem?

Comment: I suppose that in your equation the symbol `pc` means `p*c`. Then, before trying to solve for any `b`, choose a value for `b` and try to solve your equation for `p`. Before that, examine the left hand side of your equation, for example with `Manipulate`. For `b=1`, I am afraid that no solution exist; all values shown by `Manipulate` were complex and far from zero.

Comment: IN fact I forget menction that for any value taked of b, p must to satisfy  m2*b < p <m1*b

Comment: Isn't this question almost identical to your previous one from two hours ago: [Find the roots of transcendental equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175673/27951)?

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/224949-What-Does-This-Plot-Look-Like

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is ill-constrained. I can only find real roots in the rectangle `-6, <= p <= -4, 9.2 <= b <= 10.5`.

```
With[{a = 2, c = 3, m1 = 1.5, m2 = 1.49},
  ContourPlot[
    (a*b/c)*Sqrt[m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2] - 
      2 ArcTan[Sqrt[((p*c/b)^2 - m2^2)/(m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2)]] == 0, 
    {p, -6, -4}, {b, 9.2, 10.5}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `Reduce[eq && m2*b < p < m1*b, p, Reals] ` also says `False `

Answer (score 0):

```
eq = (a*b/c)*Sqrt[m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2] - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[((p*c/b)^2 - m2^2)/(m1^2 - (p*c/b)^2)]];

With[{a = 2, c = 3, m1 = 3/2, m2 = 149/100}, 
ContourPlot[{Re[eq] == 0, Im[eq] == 0}, {b, -1, 10}, {p, -5, 5}, 
MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None, 
FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"Re[eq]", "Im[eq]"}]]
```

[image]

Add more points to `PlotPoints` and increase  `MaxRecursion`(Warning!!!,uses more RAM memory and CPU time) to see more detailed plot.